# Application of 'Fermi's Golden Rule' to Economics

Tags: financial-economics

Wikipedia says:

> 'Fermi's golden rule describes a system which begins in an eigenstate, ${\displaystyle |i\rangle } |i\rangle$ , of an unperturbed Hamiltonian, $H_0$ and considers the effect of a perturbing Hamiltonian, $H'$ applied to the system. If $H'$ is time-independent, the system goes only into those states in the continuum that have the same energy as the initial state. If $H'$ is oscillating sinusoidally as a function of time (i.e. it is a harmonic perturbation) with an angular frequency $ω$, the transition is into states with energies that differ by $ħω$ from the energy of the initial state.
>   'In both cases, the transition probability per unit of time from the initial state ${\displaystyle |i\rangle } |i\rangle$  to a set of final states ${\displaystyle |f\rangle } |f\rangle$  is essentially constant.'

Does anyone know of an Econ paper which uses this? Alternatively, what might an application of it be?